# Exchange 2010 OWA authentication using email address (not UPN)

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I've set up a new Exchange 2010 server and have OWA working. However, we're having trouble using email addresses as the user name.

Our AD domain is company.local, but our email addresses are company.com. When I set OWA to authenticate using UPN I'm able to log in with name@company.local but not name@company.com.

Is there any way to allow Exchange to use email addresses as the user name or to set Active Directory to authenticate with both company.local and company.com?

Comment: An email address isn't a UPN. If you want them to logon with their email address then you'll need to create a UPN for company.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the UPN to be the same as their email addresses, by adding `company.com` as a UPN suffix:

> ### Adding a UPN Suffix to a Forest
>
> - Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts.
> - Right-click Active Directory Domains and Trusts in the Tree window pane, and then click Properties.
> - On the UPN Suffixes tab, type the new UPN suffix that you would like to add to the forrest.
> - Click Add, and then click OK.
>
> Now when you add users to the forest, you can select the new UPN
>   suffix to complete the user's logon name.

Source: [KB243629](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243629)

Comment: The second step is to change everyone's UPN to match their email address.  There's probably a powershell command to do it for all users in one shot, but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: My concern with doing this was that users wouldn't be able to log in with their company.local accounts, but I've done some testing and that doesn't appear to be the case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Is the part before @ the same as their AD login (ie. Domain login is joe@company.local and email address is joe@company.com)?  If so (or honestly even it is isn't), why mess with confusing them?  Just let them login with their Windows userID (ie. joe) and their password.

Assumption: you only have the single domain that holds Exchange users.

[image]